# How to render chart for 10,000+ records in EXT JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

Currently I am facing issue while rendering chart for large data in EXT JS. Chart gets cut or overlapped.
For example, I have 500 names on x-axis to plot then chart displays only 15 to 20 of them and others get cut. According to my view there should be scroll bar to view whole chart rather cutting the legends. I have tried to found solution for having scroll bars for such large charts but I am not able to find it.

Any other way for viewing whole chart is also accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround I can think about is 'panzoom' interaction.
Please visit link given below to see an official example with 'panzoom'.
http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/?charts=true#line-markers

With 'panzoom', you can zoom in to the chart and then scroll/pan. Zooming in to the chart would make the hidden coordinates visible.

Answer (score 0):

It may look like this because you might  have smaller space to render the chart as your data is too big. So you can try with 'pan zoom'. But I don't think so you will get a useful chart. It will still get junked.